# Change Password PHP Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am running the following code below to try and update my current password in my database to the new one being specified in the form that is being to allow for password changes. I am entering the same passwords in both fields so I don't understand why the error is occuring.

```
      <form method='post' action="changepasswordphp.php">

        <p align="center"><strong> Complete the form to change your password </strong> </p>
            <br/>
                <label><strong>Enter Old Password:</strong></label>                 
                <input name='oldpw' type='password' required='required'/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
                <label><strong>Enter New Password:</strong></label>
                <input name='newpw' type='password' required = 'required' />  
            <br/>
            <br/>
                <label><strong>Confirm New Password:</strong></label>               
                <input name='conpw' type='password' required = 'required' />
            <br/>
            <br/>
                <input type='submit' value='Submit' class ="submit" id="submit" />          
        </form>
```

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "DBPASS", "DBNAME");
if (isset($_POST['newpw'])){
$pw=$mysqli->query("SELECT userPass FROM usertable WHERE userID= '" . $_SESSION['sess_uid'] . "'");
            $row = $pw->fetch_object();
            $pawo = $row->userPass; 

if (md5($_POST['oldpw'])== $pawo){

    if (md5($_POST['newpw'])===(md5($_POST['conpw']))){
     $mysqli->query("UPDATE usertable SET userPass='" . md5($_POST['newpw']) . "' WHERE userID='" . $_SESSION['sess_uid'] . "'");
     }
    else { echo "Passwords don't match"; }
    }

else { echo "An Error Occured";}
}
```

?>
I am getting the error message "An Error Occured", I am unsure as to what is causing this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Your passwords don't match. You need to figure out why. Also, don't use `MD5()` it's been broken for a very long time.

Comment: odd, i am entering the same password in both fields

Comment: Sidenote: `session_start();` is not in your posted code (*it's required*). Yet, 9 times out of 10, it's hidden elsewhere. Why did I feel the need to ask this? Silly me.

Comment: session_start(); is included in a header.php file which works across all my pages

Comment: Then you probably need to do `if (md5($_POST['newpw']==$_POST['conpw'])){` or `if (md5($_POST['newpw'])==(md5($_POST['conpw']))){`

Comment: Are you sure the password doesn't change? Did you copy-paste the code? I am not sure about your last 'else' statement.

Comment: And, for the love of SO, remove the `@` from those queries. How else do you expect to debug anything?

Comment: I'd like to confirm, as a hint, **Don't Use md5 for Hashing passwords.** In addition try to use `salt` concatenating with the password string in hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not explicitly familiar with the MySQLi code, but this looks wrong:

```
$pw=@$mysqli->query("SELECT userPass FROM usertable WHERE userID= '" . $_SESSION['sess_uid'] . "'");
        $row = $pw->fetch_object();
        $pawo = $row->password ;
```

Is the password field `userPass` or `password`? Also, don't use MD5 (use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)) and don't use == for comparing hashed passwords. (use === instead)

Comment: userPass is the field for the password within the database

Comment: Then you need to use `$pawo = $row->userPass;`

Comment: Did that fix the issue? If not, can you verify what you're getting from the database meets your expectations?

Comment: The issue still isn't resolved but i'm certain that was part of the problem

Comment: If you're still getting the same message, you need to find out why `md5($_POST['oldpw']) != $pawo` is the case. Try adding var_dump($row) calls above that line to verify that the data coming from the database meets what you expect

Comment: I am getting the following error: 'NULL An Error Occured' I have placed the debug code above where $row is being defined

Comment: Your query is not returning the user record. You need to examine your database or your query and determine why that is. I do not have enough information to find the error

Comment: I got it to work, I ran it within the file with the form itself and for some reason it worked, however in an external php file there was problems. Thank you for the help!